# How to read a file that is located in any location on the computer?

Tags: java, parsing, text

So I have a project, and this is one of the demands:

```
     You should have a class named Project3, containing a main method.
 This program reads the levels information from a file whose name is
specified as a command-line parameter  (The file should also be
 relative to the class-path as described here:)
```

> All the file names specified in the levels and block definition files
> should be relative to the class path. The reason we want them to be
> relative to the class path is that later we will be able to read the
> files from inside a jar, something we can not do with regular File
> references.
>
> To get an input stream relative to the class path (even if it's inside
> a jar), use the following:
>
> InputStream is =
> ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.png");
> The idea is to keep a folder with files(definitions and images) and
> then add that folder to the class path when running the JVM:
>
> java -cp bin:resources ...  If you don't add the resources folder to
> you class path you wont be able to load them with the command from
> above.

```
 When run without parameters, your program should read a default level
 file, and run the game accordingly. The location of the default level
 file should be hard-coded in your code, and be relative to the
 classpath_.
```

When run without parameters, your program should read a default level file, and run the game accordingly. The location of the default level file should be hard-coded in your code, and be relative to the classpath_.

The part of the code that handles the input is:

```
  public Void run() throws IOException {
    LevelReader level = new LevelReader();
    List<level> chosenLevels = new ArrayList<>();
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            File f = new File(args[0]);
            if (f.exists()) {
                        chosenLevels = level.makeLevel(args[0]);
                    }
        }
    if (chosenLevels.size() == 0) {
        game.runLevels(defaultLevels);
    } else {
        game.runLevels(chosenLevels);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So my question is:

- An argument should be the full path of a file which means:
  D:\desktop\level3.txt

  Is it possible to read a file from every location on my computer?
  Because right now I can do it only if my text file is in the
  project's directory (not even in the src folder).
- I can't understand the rest of their demands. What does is mean "should be hard-coded in your code, and be relative to the
  classpath_." and why is it related to InputStream method(?)

I'm confused all over this.
Thanks.

Comment: This Web page may be helpful: [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)

Answer (score 3):

A *classpath resource* is not the same as a file.

As you have correctly stated, the full path of a file is something like `D:\desktop\level3.txt`.

But if ever want to distribute your application so it can run on other computers, which probably won’t have that file in that location, you have two choices:

- Ask the user to tell the program where to find the file on their computer.
- Bundle the file with the compiled program.

If you place a non-.class file in the same place as .class files, it’s considered a resource.  Since you don’t know at runtime where your program’s class files are located,¹ you use the `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` method, which is specifically designed to look in the classpath.

The getResource* methods have the additional benefit that they will work both when you are developing, and when the program is packaged as a .jar file.  Individual entries in a .jar file are not separate files and cannot be read using the `File` or `FileInputStream` classes.

If I understand your assignment correctly, the default level file should be an application resource, and the name of that resource is what should be hard-coded in your program.  Something like:

```
InputStream is;
if (args.length > 0) {
    is = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(args[0]));
} else {
    // No argument provided, so use program's default level data.
    is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("defaultlevel.txt");
}

chosenLevels = level.makeLevel(is);
```

---

¹ You may find some pages that claim you can determine the location of a running program’s code using `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`, but getCodeSource() may return null, depending on the JVM and ClassLoader implementation, so this is not reliable.

Comment: my program works ok on intellij but when I try to run it from jar it doesn't work. It does runs the text file but not the jpg file inside of it.

Comment: What does “the jpg file inside of it” mean?  Is the image data inside the text file?  Or do you have a file name inside the text file?  Obviously, a path to a file will not be valid on other computers.  If the image is part of your program, then it too should be an application resource, and the text files should refer to the image using a resource path which is relative to the classpath root, not a file name.

Comment: I have a function in a class that does the following:   InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(backgrounds/bg.jpg);
            this.image = ImageIO.read(is); ///// and this brings up null and the program can't "find" or get access or I don't know what to that image. and this not a code problem because it works perfectlly in inellij. Only when I compile it to jar file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Examine the contents of your .jar file.  Does it have a `backgrounds/bg.jpg` entry in it?  (You should be able to use your IDE to examine the .jar file.  If that doesn’t work, make a copy of the .jar file and change the copy’s extension to `.zip`, then open it with any zip tool.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it doesn't seem like they're asking you to read from anywhere on disk, just from within your class path. So that seems fine.

The second question, "What does is mean 'should be hard-coded in your code, and be relative to the classpath'?". You are always going to have a default level file in your project directory. Define the path to this file as a String in your program and that requirement will be satisfied. It's related to the InputStream because the stream requires a location to read in from.